# Package Manager Console Enable-Migrations CommandNotFoundException in visual studio pro s2017

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

I tried to run the command 'Enable-Migrations' in the microsoft sample project https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/ with visual studio professional 2017, But I got the message:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verif
y that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:18
+ Enable-Migrations <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-Migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

```
1、I have tried the re-starting Visual Studio and re-install EntityFramework Packages using "Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease" but these are invalid
```

```
2、I have tried upgrade my powershell to 4.9.3.5777, but it is also invalid
```

```
3、I have tried Import-Module ProjectPath\packages\EntityFramework.6.3.0\tools\EntityFramework6.psd1,but invalid
```

BTW,I am using EntityFramework6.3.0.

Comment: BTW, I am also using Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy <PolicyName> -Scope <scope> change LocalMachine and CurrenUser's ExecutionPolicy, but invalid.

Comment: BTW, I am using .NET FrameWork 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resloved the question by installing EntityFramework5.0 with .net Framework4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```